# Count number of divs by id within a specified div - js

Tags: javascript

Below is the div structure. How can I find the number of divs which has the id of `_1item` only inside `categoryFurniture` in javascript?

I tried this by doing some google research but no luck.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=_1item]').length
```

div structure example:

```
<div id="categoryFurniture">
   <div id= "xyz_1item"></div>
   <div id= "abc_1item"></div>
   <div id= "xyz_2item"></div>
   <div id= "pqr_1item"></div>
   <div id= "pqr_2item"></div>
</div>

<div id="categoryFruits">
   <div id= "xyz_1item"></div>
   <div id= "abc_2item"></div>
   <div id= "xyz_3item"></div>
   <div id= "pqr_1item"></div>
   <div id= "pqr_3item"></div>
</div>
```

output should be 3

Comment: perhaps add #categoryFurniture to your selector?

Comment: Try $= instead of ^=. $= means ends with and ^= means starts with

Comment: Is that your actual HTML markup? Or did you forgot to add `id` to all those divs? (which btw is bad practice).

Comment: why add jquery to query a couple elements?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[id$=_1furniture]').length

Comment: @aug: that was a typo. fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [id](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors) and [attribute ends selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)

```
document.querySelectorAll('#categoryFurniture [id$=_1item]')
```

then you can read the `length` property of the nodeList returned above to get the count

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b038sr17/)

Comment: How would I get the count if I wanted the count of `_1item` and `_2item`?  `document.querySelectorAll('#categoryFurniture [id$=_1item , id$=_2item ] ')` ?

Comment: @Beki in that case `document.querySelector('#categoryFurniture').querySelectorAll('[id$="_1item"], [id$="_2item"]')`

Comment: @Beki or `document.getElementById('categoryFurniture').querySelectorAll('[id$="_1item"], [id$="_2item"]')`

Answer (score 1):

This will return you `3` as count

```
document.querySelector("#categoryFurniture").querySelectorAll('[id$=_1furniture]').length
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('#categoryFurniture [id$=_1furniture]').length
```

EDIT:

Based on your update on question, you need to replace `_1furniture` with `_1item`

```
document.querySelectorAll('#categoryFurniture [id$=_1item]').length
```

Comment: How would I get the count if I wanted the count of `_1item` and `_2item`? `document.querySelectorAll('#categoryFurniture [id$=_1item , id$=_2item ] ').length`?